# Migration issues when adding ForeignKey to model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-south

I currently have a site which hosts apps and has a database of users. Now I want to connect the two so Apps can have authors (i.e. the users)

**Update**: A few more pertinent details added below and I'm using django-registration.

[Following this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641052/adding-foreign-key-to-django-model) as well as the Django docs, I started by adding the `author` line to my apps model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class App(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

However, when I visit my apps from django admin I get the error **DatabaseError at /admin/apps/app/ ...no such column: apps_app.author_id**

There are obviously more steps I need to do for this feature, but I'm curious why this simple addition is throwing an error.

I'm using South for migration and ran

```
./manage.py schemamigration apps --auto
```

For the one-off value, I set it to "zero" since it expects an `int()`

```
./manage.py migrate apps
```

This didn't work so I did

```
./manage.py migrate apps --fake
```

Then the previous command again, no --fake.

Also, per the linked SO question, am I supposed to also create `class User(User)` in apps/models.py?

**Update 2** I just created a new django app (with `.manage.py startapp...` not to be confused with my "app" object). I went through the steps of creating adding this foreign key and it worked fine. My only conclusion from this is that it must be a South migration issue, and not actually anything wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this both on my local and stage and this is the best solution I could come up with.

Because, for some reason, South does not "see" that the author column needs to be added to the apps table, there is a manual schema migration option with the `--add-field` flag.

I did:

```
/manage.py schemamigration apps --add-field app.author
```

Then

```
./manage.py migrate apps
```

If that last one doesn't work, try

```
./manage.py migrate apps --fake 000x
```

where `000x` is the migration number. You can get this from the output of the first step.

Then restart and it should be fixed. I've been doing this over and over and found I got the most success when I was most specific with South. I would recommend specifying the migration number each time. The migration number carries the directions for that specific change and should directly apply the database transformation.

Answer (score 0):

> ./manage.py migrate apps
>
> This didn't work so I did

How you mean it did not work? What error did you receive?

For similiar situations I usually create FK with `null=True`, run this migration and then create datamigration, that will populate FK.

> Also, per the linked SO question, am I supposed to also create class User(User) in apps/models.py?

If you want to link author to django auth user, then just import it from django.contrib.auth.models. Otherwise, yes, you need a `User` (or better `Author`) model that will subclass `django.db.models.Model` and not `User`

Comment: Okay, I forgot to mention that. I am importing django.contrib.auth.models. Just a sec, I'll test your solution.

Comment: Still getting the same error, though I wonder if not using `null=True` the first few times irreversibly screwed up the db. 

The error from south was/is "django.db.utils.DatabaseError: table "_south_new_apps_app" already exists"

Comment: No, nevermind that theory. I tried just making a new name for it,`appauthor` but now it says `no such column: apps_app.appauthor_id`.